# Using playframework without sbt plugin

Tags: playframework, sbt, build-system, sbt-plugin

I like playframework, but I don't like sbt. Finally there's a good alternative: [mill](http://www.lihaoyi.com/mill/); but I cannot use it with Playframework because, regardless of the minimality of it, play is more than just a couple of libraries. Play is an sbt plugin, which I'm pretty sure does the compilation of assets and routes.
I'm wondering if I can use play as only a library (or a collection of libraries), if yes, which libraries, and how can I do the routing, and kickstarting of the app (assuming I don't care about compilation of assets).